# Issues installing Perl modules manually

Tags: perl, cpan

I'm trying to install the DateTime module on my system. I'm using [this](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/09/how-to-install-perl-modules-manually-and-using-cpan-command/) guide.

First up I just used wget to download, untarred, did a `perl Makefile.pm`, and then `make`

I then ran in to problems with dependencies and saw I could use CPAN instead.

Running `install DateTime` in cpan seemed to work, and if I try to install it again I get `DateTime is up to date (1.51).`

The issue though is that now when I try to run my script I get `Can't locate namespace/autoclean.pm in @INC`, and trying to install that via cpan results in failures like:
`Warning: no success downloading '/root/.cpan/sources/authors/id/n/n/n/na/namespace/autoclean.pm.tmp28533'. Giving up on it. at /usr/share/perl5/CPAN/Distribution.pm line 379`

Is there something I'm missing? Did I screw up my install by trying to install Datetime via wget instead of cpan?

Comment: Are you running `cpan namespace::autoclean` or `cpan namespace/autoclean.pm`? You should use the first one.

Comment: Re "*Did I screw up my install by trying to install Datetime via wget instead of cpan?*", No

Comment: @mob Oddly enough, `cpan namespace::autoclean` seems to have fixed my issue, even though I thought that's what I was doing when I ran `cpan` and then issued `namespace/autoclean` from there. Thank you.

Comment: FWIW, that guide is wrong, because it doesn't tell you how to install dependencies. Using the CPAN installer to begin with will handle all of this: `cpan DateTime`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't show what command you issued, but it wasn't correct.<sup>[1]</sup> `cpan` was trying to download

```
authors/id/n/n/n/na/namespace/autoclean.pm
```

(`autoclean.pm` by CPAN author "namespace".)

The correct file is

```
authors/id/E/ET/ETHER/namespace-autoclean-0.29.tar.gz
```

(`namespace-autoclean-0.29.tar.gz` by CPAN author "ETHER".)

The correct shell command is

```
cpan namespace::autoclean
```

From within the `cpan` interactive interface, the correct command is

```
install namespace::autoclean
```

---

1. I think you did the equivalent of

   ```
   cpan namespace/autoclean.pm
   ```

   When you provide a path, it's expected to be a path to a *distribution*, including the author ID. For example, you could use the following to install a specific version of the distribution:

   ```
   cpan ETHER/namespace-autoclean-0.29.tar.gz
   ```

   Note that newer versions of `cpan` first check if the path corresponds to a known module, so `cpan namespace/autoclean.pm` would actually have worked for newer versions of `cpan`.